# Xcode auto alignment and constraints - equal distances between several images

Tags: xcode

I have nine images ad I want them to display in a single column on the device. The images should retain their original height and width (that I will set) and the only thing that should change according to the screen height should be the distance between the images.

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem - I tried using a container, but it didn't turn out as I expected. Should I set the constraints programmatically? And if so, how? What should the constraints be if I want the images to be from top to bottom of he screen?

Comment: if you are targeting for ios9, use stack view. Else do the native way of constraining the elements on storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a stack view:

- On iOS, UIStackView provides `UIStackViewDistributionEqualSpacing`, which I believe will arrange images as you want
- On Mac, NSStackView can automatically space images as you describe if the individual image views are all in the same gravity and retain their sizes at a high enough priority (using constraints or content hugging priority)